# How could I get the total number inside a java xml tap?

Tags: java, xml, nodes

For xml file view:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EXAMPLE DATE="20160830">
 <SUB NUM="1">
  <NAME>Peter</NAME>
 </SUB>
 <SUB NUM="2">
  <NAME>Mary</NAME>
 </SUB>
</EXAMPLE>
```

After I setup a NodeList for check the document,
I want it can be count the "NAME" Tap in each "SUB NUM="[x]""
For the code that I set for it:

```
NodeList nList= doc.getElementsByTagName("NUM"); // doc has been set correct and get successful
```

The nList.length will return "2" due to xml having 2 of the tap which is named as: "NUM", but I want to check each of the group only.
Is any Idea how could I get the length like:

SUB NUM [1] Found: [1] Length with tap name: [NAME]
SUB NUM [2] Found: [1] Length with tap name: [NAME]

Comment: You can get this with a one-line XPath expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done as follows. Just the hashmap printing using a JAVA8 syntax. You should be able to iterate normally and print if you are not on 8.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class NumCountHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> countOfNum = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SUB")) {
            String attributeNum = attributes.getValue("NUM");
            // System.out.println("Here" + qName +"" + );
            if (countOfNum.containsKey(attributeNum)) {
                Integer count = countOfNum.get(attributeNum);
                countOfNum.put(attributeNum, new Integer(count.intValue() + 1));
            } else {
                countOfNum.put(attributeNum, new Integer(1));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String xml = "<EXAMPLE DATE=\"20160830\"> <SUB NUM=\"1\">  <NAME>Peter</NAME> </SUB> <SUB NUM=\"2\">  <NAME>Mary</NAME> </SUB></EXAMPLE>";
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            NumCountHandler userhandler = new NumCountHandler();
            saxParser.parse(is, userhandler);

            userhandler.countOfNum
                    .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("SUB NUM [" + k + "]" + "Length with tap name :[" + v + "]"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
SUB NUM [1]Length with tap name :[1]
SUB NUM [2]Length with tap name :[1]
```